# Powershell not printing accented characters correctly

Tags: powershell, utf-8, ascii

So i'm trying to rename a file using powershell, the script should remove all special chars.

Simple right?  Not so fast.  Accented characters are not being parsed correctly

This is the script i'm using, called `renamefiles.ps1`

```
param([string]$complfn) #Must be the first statement in your script
```

Tried both of these without any difference, either using one of them or none

```
#$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding
#[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
write-host $complfn

$encodage = New-Object System.Text.ASCIIEncoding 
[System.Console]::OutputEncoding = $encodage
Write-Host $complfn

$encodage = New-Object System.Text.utf8encoding 
[System.Console]::OutputEncoding = $encodage
Write-Host $complfn

$newcomplfn  = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("Cyrillic").GetBytes($complfn))
Write-Host $newcomplfn
```

I'm using it like this
    `powershell.exe -file renamefiles.ps1 -complfn "ásdfésdf.txt"`

This is the output i'm getting:

```
Ã¡sdfÃ©sdf.txt
Ã¡sdfÃ©sdf.txt
Ã¡sdfÃ©sdf.txt
asdfesdf.txt
```

I see the last command is effectively replacing the accented characters, but do you know what can I use to display the orignal parameter (file name)?

Comment: `powershell.exe -file renamefiles.ps1 -complfn "ásdfésdf.txt"` you doing that from what? From command line? From PowerShell script file (.ps1)? Batch file (.bat .cmd)?

Comment: @PetSerAl from ISE, it's in a ps1 file, but my goal will be to run this script from a right click command menu, possibly a.bat file

Comment: Do that `[Console]::OutputEncoding=[Text.Encoding]::Unicode` before and inside `renamefiles.ps1` script.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks for your help.  i tried it but no luck.  I'm using win10x64

Comment: Do you need to see the character?  foreach ($c in [char[]]"ásdfésdf.txt") { Write-Output ([int]$c) } will get you each one's character code; check that against a range of known "good" characters?

Comment: @DarkMoon thanks I ended up using a different codepage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding `chcp 65001` to the script

This changes the codepage to Unicode

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by setting ANSI format instead of UTF-8 (without BOM) in Notepad ++